# NHibernate: c# action on cascade deletion

Tags: c#, nhibernate, cascading-deletes, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I've implemented one-to-many code mapping with cascade deletion. I have associated file with child entity. I want to delete file automatically on child cascade deletion.
How can it be implemented?

Comment: Maybe you could include some code examples you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that NHibernate supports Listeners on Configuration level. It's not perfect, but better than nothing. Simplified example:

```
var deleteListener = new DeleteListener();
_configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.Delete, deleteListener);

class DeleteListener : DefaultDeleteEventListener {
    public override void OnDelete(DeleteEvent e, ISet<object> transientEntities) {
        MyEntity entity = e.Entity as MyEntity;
        if (entity != null) {
            // code for file deletion
        }
        base.OnDelete(e, transientEntities);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use an [`IInterceptor`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html#objectstate-interceptors) too, deriving from `EmptyInterceptor`. But that would probably not be better than [events](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html#objectstate-events).